# Python take a variable number of inputs?

Tags: python, input

Is there a way to have python take a number of inputs based on what the user says like this?

```
x = input("how many numbers do you have?")
```

and if x = 5, the program would ask for number one, number two, number three, etc...

Is this possible?

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "loops"

Comment: Yes. Just take in that number, and use it as a looping variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
amount = int(input("Enter the amount of numbers that you have: "))

numbers = []
for i in range(amount):
    new = input('Enter number {}: '.format(i+1))
    numbers.append(new)

print(numbers)
```

You should probably do some reading on loops in Python.

Comment: I would do `'Enter number {}:'.format(i+1)` Noone shows love from str.format :c

Comment: @Sabyasachi you're right, that looks much cleaner. Edited.